# Storing .env variables and initializing modules for Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, google-secret-manager

I am trying to figure out the best way to store environment variables and initialize modules for cloud functions. From my understanding, there are 3 main ways, each with a potential drawback:

- Using `.env` variables (what I am currently doing) - This creates a runtime environment variable in google cloud platform when I deploy the cloud functions which seems insecure and unnecessary for a variable that is only used for module instantiation.
- Using `defineSecret` - It appears secrets are only available at runtime (as per the documentation: "the values of secrets are hidden until execution of the function, you cannot use them while configuring your function."), which limits their usefulness for initializing modules and using `defineString` seems to defeat the purpose of using firebase secrets
- Using `functions.config()`  - This works to initialize modules (and is the recommended way, I believe) but as per the documentation this method will not work with 2nd generation functions: "**Caution:** Environment configuration with `functions.config()` is supported only in the first-generation Cloud Functions SDK. Using `functions.config()` with the 2nd-generation SDK, currently in public preview, fails at deployment."

Here is an example:
I have a cloud function that sends an email. I am initializing the customerio client outside of the cloud function, using .env variables:

```
// Initialise customerio client
const customerioApi = process.env.CUSTOMERIO_API_KEY as string;
const client = new APIClient(customerioApi);
```

What are the best practices when it comes to initializing modules for cloud functions? Should it be done outside like I am doing now? Or is it more secure to initialize them inside the cloud function where I can use firebase secrets as it is in runtime like this?

```
// inside cloud function
const customerioApi = defineSecret("CUSTOMERIO_API_KEY");
const client = new APIClient(customerioApi.value());
```

Am I missing something or misreading the docs? Or is my current method of using .env and storing them as runtime environment variables in GCP secure?

Comment: This may be off-topic for SO as I don't think their is any quantative way to assess each option you provided. It's your job as the dev to weigh the risks of each approach and select what works for your project's requirements. I would opt for lazy initialisation inside the scope of a Cloud Function. This prevents it being initialized until it is actually needed by a function and allows it to be skipped for functions that don't need it. This also allows you to use secret manager if you want to treat your key as a secret.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to manage secrets and you need to deploy your function using the [`--set-secrets`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--set-secrets) flag with `gcloud functions deploy`. These secrets are made available as environment variables automatically when the function is deployed and since they are environment variables they can be accessed anywhere in the code.

If you have a function that looks like this:

```js
import { type Context } from '@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/functions'
import { type PubsubMessage } from '@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/publisher'

const mySecretValue = process.env.MY_SECRET_VALUE
console.log(`The secret is ${mySecretValue as string}`)

export const testFunction = async (message: PubsubMessage, context: Context): Promise<void> => {
  // do something
}
```

Then you could [create a secret in Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-create-secret-console) named `mySecretValue`, grant the [*Secret Manager Secret Accessor* role](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control) to the service account that runs the function, and then deploy your function with `gcloud functions deploy`:

```bash
gcloud functions deploy testFunction \
  --set-secrets=MY_SECRET_VALUE=mySecretValue:latest \
  --trigger-topic=test-topic
```